# uploading .mov file

Tags: php

I am uploading the video files with flash uploader object and then convert it into .mp4 format through Zencoder. Firstly file gets uploaded into server folder. All the files with extension .wmv , .flv etc. are gets moved to folder, But when I upload .mov file then, it does not gets uploaded into server folder. Is there need to change any server settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this async, upload the file, store it (here you make sure your file is saved properly, and then launch the encoding process).

It seems you may be running into some timeout issues, since no especial treatment is needed for .mov files in php or apache.

Comment: yes, but simple function I have used, move_uploaded_file but it doesn't work for .mov files.

Comment: for all .mov files? isn't it a filename issue?